# Collision not working if isTrigger is checked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on 2d Unity project, this is what I have so far:

1. 2 sprites, with 2DBoxCollision, 2DRiggidBody
2. On sprite A, i checked onTrigger
3. Create an C# script, Overrider OnTriggerEnter2D and attach to sprite A

But 2 object is no collision with each other no more.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Physics collision is disabled if isTrigger is checked, that is because there are functions such as OnTriggerEnter, this function cannot be called if no object can enter the trigger, as you set in the inspector "isTrigger".

What you can do, is use OnCollision to check if objects are colliding, or have two objects one within the other and have the outer layer have a isTrigger,

in short terms, physics collision is ignored when the object as isTrigger not really an issue just a basic function.